# @depends flag breaks the arguments in my PHPUnit function

Tags: phpunit

In the code below, testFunctionA outputs true, while testFunctionB outputs null. Is this a known error and can I get around it without getting rid of my @depends flags?

```
public function testFunctionA( $x = true ) {
  var_dump( $x ); // outputs true
}

/*
* @depends testFunctionA
*/
public function testFunctionB( $y = true ) {
  var_dump( $y ); // outputs NULL
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @depends annotation does a bit more than you are thinking it does here. Mainly, the return value from testFunctionA is passed into testFunctionB. Since testFunctionA doesn't return anything, testFunctionB is getting passed a null value.

See the PHPUnit [test dependencies](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies) docs for more information.

There is a difference between providing a null parameter and no parameter at all to testFunctionB. Only with nothing provided will $y default to true.